# Select an option after initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have found a lot of answers on stack on this but none of them work for me.
What I want is to select the first option after the box is initialized because currently it just selects a blank option which isn't even available after initialization.

My HTML:

```
              <select [(ngModel)]="examen_id" name="examen_id" class="form-control" formControlName="examInput">
                <option *ngFor="let examen of examensStudent" [ngValue]="examen.id">{{examen.naam}}</option>
              </select>
```

And in Typescript this is what I tried:

```
export class StudentUploadComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() examensStudent: Examen[] = [];
    examen_id: string;

 ngOnInit(){
    this.serv.getExams().subscribe(data => {
      this.examensStudent = data;

      this.examen_id = '1'; // This is where I try to change it to option 1
    });
 }
```

Comment: try `this.examen_id = 1;` instead

Comment: I'm so stupid.. I had to change it in a number indeed. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've been there too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `id` of your `examen` is a number, the ngModel is of type `string`.

Angular uses the `===` operator which is used to check variable types.

Therefore, `'1' != 1` and the `select` fail to select the right option.

`this.examen_id = 1;` should fix it.

*NB: don't forget to change the declaration of the variable to type `number`*